# Chatty AI that saves .txt files to remember

Tags: windows, ai, batch

This is a basic AI that I created.  It has a teach function that creates a .txt file with user inputed info for future use.  If you type teachme you have the option to type in something that you have already taught it and it will tell you what you taught it.
Any tips to make this better are appreciated.  (I'm OK if you tell me I completely messed up.)

```
@echo off
COLOR A
     echo.>"c:\users\Joe\desktop\charinfo.txt"
    if not exist charinfo.txt goto :charinfo
    goto :load
TITLE 
:charinfo
cls
echo Make an avatar please.
echo.
set /p name=Name:
cls
set /p sex=Sex:
echo.
cls
echo What would you like my name to be?
set /p botname=
TITLE %botname%
cls
set /p colour=Program Color ID:
cls
(
echo %name%
echo %sex%
echo %botname%
echo %colour%
 ) > charinfo.txt


cls
:load
(
set /p name=        
set /p sex=
set /p botname=
set /p colour=
) < charinfo.txt

:start
color %colour%
TITLE %botname%
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Hello, my name is '%botname%'
if %name%==restart goto :start
echo.
:q1
echo Hi %name%!  How are you doing?
set /p mood=
if %mood%==good goto :good
if %mood%==bad goto :bad
if %mood%==fine goto :good
if %mood%==awesome goto :awesome
if %mood%==ok goto :ok
if %mood%==* goto :ok
if %mood%==bored goto :bored
if %mood%==idk goto :bored
if %mood%==crappy goto :bad
if %mood%==happy goto :good
if %mood%==sad goto :bad
if %mood%==great goto :awesome
if %mood%==meh goto :meh
if %mood%==restart goto :start
if %mood%==teach goto :q3
if %mood%==teachme goto :learned
if %mood%==tips goto :tips



:good
echo That's great! I'm doing pretty good today as well.
goto :q2
:bad
echo Well that sux.  I hope you get better though!
goto :q2
:awesome
echo Cool! My day has been pretty good.
goto :q2
:ok
echo That's good, the day can only get better!
goto :q2
:bored
echo Well find something to do then!
goto :q2
:meh
echo Well at least you're not doing too bad!
goto :q2
echo.
:teaching

cls
echo In one word tell me what you want to teach me?
echo.
set /p cat=:
if exist "c:\users\Joe\desktop\AI_BRAIN(MINE)\brain\%cat%.txt" goto :already
if not exist "c:\users\Joe\desktop\AI_BRAIN(MINE)\brain\%cat%.txt" goto :idk



:learned
cls
echo If you've told me about it!  I'll remember it
echo what do you want to learn about?
echo.
set /p cat=:
if not exist "c:\users\Joe\desktop\AI_Brain(MINE)\brain\%cat%.txt" goto :idk
(
::set /p cat=
set /p catinfo=
) < "c:\users\Joe\desktop\AI_Brain(MINE)\brain\%cat%.txt"
type "c:\users\Joe\desktop\AI_Brain(MINE)\brain\%cat%.txt"
::pause >nul
goto :p5





:idk
cls
echo I don't know anything about %cat%. Can you tell me what you know.
echo.
set /p catinfo=:
echo %catinfo% >> "c:\users\chuggaaconroy\desktop\AI_Brain(MINE)\brain\%cat%.txt"
set txt=That's cool, now I know.
set txt=Cool now I know about %cat%.
goto :q4

:q2
cls
echo Have you done anything cool today?
set /p activity=
if %activity%==restart goto :start
if %activity%==teach goto :teaching
if %activity%==teachme goto :learned
if %activity%==tips goto :tips
echo cool!
echo I havn't really done much today, I kind've just sat around all day :\
:q3
cls
echo Would you like to teach me about something?
set /p answer1=Say Yes or no:

if %answer1%==no goto :info1
if %answer1%==yes goto :teaching

:info1
cls
echo OK!  If you ever want to teach me something please type in "teach"
goto :q4
:already
echo I think I've already learnt that!
goto :q3
:tips
cls
echo If at any time you would like to restart, please type 'restart' without the '' then press enter
echo.
echo If you want to teach me something, type in teach
echo.
echo if you want me to tell you something that you've taught me. Type in teachme
echo.
echo If you would like to view these tips again, type in tips at anytime.
goto :end
:q4
echo Awesome! now I know!  If you want me to tell you about it later, just type in teachme.
goto :end
:p5
echo Told you I would remember!
goto :end
:end
echo You have reached the end
pause
```

Comment: While your code is verbose enough to read what it's doing without too much effort, could you add a description of what you're doing and why (what problem does it solve?) to your question?

Comment: Well I made this for my younger sister as she is starting to get into coding.  She wanted to have a "chatbot" to go off of to make her own.  While making this I started to get interested so I made it a little more complicated by adding the teach function, (while still making it simple enough that she could understand).  I've been stuck though because I'm not sure how to make it better in the sense that if you just type in a word you want to teach it will know what you're talking about and not just go to an error message.

Comment: @PixelPiggy I suggest a scripting language like Ruby or Python. They are much easier and compact than Bash